# How to have user input text to field, have text sent to database, and then displayed on a page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, comments

I am creating a website for a small personal project. Basically I need a text field where the user puts a quote, a submit button which sends it to a data base, and then all the quotes in the database displayed below that. I cannot figure out how to do this.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/E8cKVj9]

I have tried to use Javascript to display a quote after it is submitted, however everything disappears upon reloading the page, and it is not saved to a database.

Comment: Adding screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try the following

> first Set action form to php file **(index.php)**.

```
<form method="Post" action="form.php">
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="label">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" >
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="form-group">
    <label for="f">Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" >
</fieldset>
<button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

> **form.php this will be second page**

```
    <?php 
 $server="localhost";
 $username ="root";
 $password ="";
 $database ="you_database";

 $connection =mysqli_connect($server ,$username ,$password,$database); //start connection 

 if ($connection==TRUE) // test connection
  {
    echo "connected succefull";
 }


 if (isset($_POST['submit']))  //test submit name in form
 {
// declare parameter to initialized in text fild in form 
// and those fild should appear in serve (apache mysql)
    $username =$_POST['username'];
    $lastname =$_POST['lastname'];

    $query ="INSERT INTO your_table  VALUES(NULL, '$username' ,'$lastname' ");
    $result =mysqli_query($connection ,$query);

    if ($result == TRUE) {

        echo "data insert succefull";
    }else{
        echo "failed to insert";
    }

 }
 mysqli_error($connection);


 ?>
```

Comment: So what else do I need to use this? Do I need to create a database?

Comment: Yes! you have to create a database with a Field ,username, lastname

Comment: And then how do I turn around and retrieve and display it?

Comment: **Use this link to solve your problem** [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use server side code to achieve this

Javascript is client side so data cannot be inserted to a database

These links should help you achieve what you need

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on several ways:

**Standard html form**

1. Set action form to php file. If you click submit then page will be refeshed.
2. In php script you should veryfy if data are correct and sava data into database
   or file
3. Redirect user back to page with form. Bellow form you should fetch and display
   rows from database.

**Using AJAX - without refreshing page**

1. After click send button you can verify data in Javascript and send
   them (via AJAX) to backend (php script)
2. In backend verify if data are ok and save them to db/file. Backend should output JSON results. Message info ans status.
3. In Javascript you should parse JSON result and make some actions like, show message to user.
4. Next you can fetch (via ajax) list of all (or eg. last 10) rows from table in database